# Using Nuxt 3 public directory without rebuilding

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

The `public` dir does not work in Nuxt 3 as a `static` dir in Nuxt 2. In Nuxt 2 I used the backend to put dynamic content in `static`, and then used in the application. In Nuxt 3 from the `public` dir the public content is placed in the `.output` and `.nuxt/dist/server` and `.nuxt/dist/client` dirs during the build of the project and pulled from there. Where to put files dynamicly so that they can be used in app without rebuilding the application?

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to use a CDN for that in combinaison with the nuxt/image module. You can find the list of supported providers in their docs.
https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: Of course, for pictures I do that. But I also have another task. Ok, then the question is: if I automatically rebuild the project every time I change the file, is this a good solution? And how to do it? And is it reliable? And how to find out that the build went well or with errors in order to run `pm2 start`

Comment: Yes it is a good solution, in fact, that is exactly what vercel, netlify and other main hosting services are doing with the JAMstack. The entire site rebuilds everytime there is a new commit on the main branch. I'd advice looking into CI/CD with github/gitlab actions or another service of your choosing.